# Create nested dynamic input in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, dynamic, html-table

I have this form that the user can input multiple data using dynamic input of jquery. I want to add a new variant when the button is click and add also a dynamic input inside it. My problem is when im adding new data to the newly created variant it also add to the previous variant. I want it to be seperate when im adding value.
`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter= 0;
function add_variant(counter){
    var html='';
    html+= '<div class="row" id="variantTitle"><div class="col"><div class="form-group"><label for="variant">Select Variant</label><select class="custom-select border-success variant" name="variant" id="variant"><option value="">Select</option><?php echo fill_variant_box($conn); ?></select></div></div></div>';
    
    return html;
}


    function add_input_field(){
      $('#testBtn').remove();
      $('#cancelBtn').remove();

      var html='';
     
      html+='<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><th>Category</th><th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Button</th></tr>';
      html+='<tbody class="dynamicAdd"><tr>';
      html+='<td><select class="custom-select category border-success" name="category" id="category"><option value="-Select-">-Select-</option><?php echo fill_category_select_box($conn); ?></select></td>'
      html+='<td><input class="form-control border-success name_items" id="name_items" name="name_items" autocomplete="off"></td>';
      html+='<td><input class="form-control quantity border-success" type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"></td>';
      html+= '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAdd">Add</button></td>'
      html+='</tr></tbody></table>';

     
      return html;
    }
    var appendedTable = '<tr>'+
    '<td><select class="custom-select category border-success" name="category" id="category"><option value="-Select-">-Select-</option><?php echo fill_category_select_box($conn); ?></select></td>'+
    '<td><input class="form-control border-success name_items" id="name_items" name="name_items" autocomplete="off"></td>'+
    '<td><input class="form-control quantity border-success" type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"></td>'+
    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnRemove">Remove</button></td></tr>';

    $('#add-form').append(add_input_field());
    $(document).on('click','#btnRemove', function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    $('#add-form').append('<button  type="button" class="btn addDonate" id="testBtn">Save</button>');
    $('#add-form').append('<button type="button" class="btn  cancelBtn" id="cancelBtn">Cancel</button>');

    $(document).on('click', '#btnAdd',function(){
        $('.dynamicAdd').append(appendedTable);
    });
   
  
});
```

`then this is the code when im adding new variant`

```
$(document).on('click','#addVar',function(){

function add_input_field(){
      $('#testBtn').remove();
      $('#cancelBtn').remove();

      var html='';
     
      html+='<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><th>Category</th><th>Item Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Button</th></tr>';
      html+='<tbody class="dynamicAdd"><tr>';
      html+='<td><select class="custom-select category border-success" name="category" id="category"><option value="-Select-">-Select-</option><?php echo fill_category_select_box($conn); ?></select></td>'
      html+='<td><input class="form-control border-success name_items" id="name_items" name="name_items" autocomplete="off"></td>';
      html+='<td><input class="form-control quantity border-success" type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"></td>';
      html+= '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAdd">Add</button></td>'
      html+='</tr></tbody></table>';

     
      return html;
    }
    $('#add-form').append(add_input_field());
});
```

`

I want to create a dynamic input within a dynamic input.

Comment: You've included the code you use to *add* the table (twice), but not included the relevant code which "*adds new data to the newly created [variant]*"

Comment: Note: IDs should (must) be unique - if you have `#btnRemove` on every line, then it's not unique.   Use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: Yes because I didnt know how can it be seperated to previous one.  How can i achieve it?

Comment: What is the relevant code for that?